# Тире в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания?

В настоящее время логика, психология, рисование, конституция, а главное  -  философия как предметы обучения в школе и вузе практически не используются.

Answer (score 5):

Да, тире верно поставлено.

Comment: София, вы пишите, что во втором примере убрать "а главное" нельзя. Если нельзя убрать, то это еще не значит, что это не вводное слово. К тому же, если считать это членом предложения (подлежащим), то изменится смысл предложения. Ср.: "Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно"  (с водным словом "главное", смысл таков: важно, чтобы занимательно). С членом предложения (подлежащим), смысл таков: чтобы ГЛАВНОЕ было занимательно. Но какое главное? И что это за главное? О нем ничего не говорится. Поэтому здесь "главное" - это вводное слово.

Comment: 1) Я понимаю предложение так: Детали - это не главное (их можно опустить), главное - это чтобы было интересно. 2) По поводу вводных слов. Вводное слово не входит в состав предложения по определению, поэтому его можно изъять. Если этого нельзя сделать, то вводное слово получает другую функцию (сказуемое, обстоятельство, частица, союз, часть союза).

Comment: Цитирую Розенталя. Следует, однако, иметь в виду, что если с изъятием слова или словосочетания структура предложения распадается, то это еще не служит доказательством того, что изъятые слова - члены предложения. А вы подумайте, может, и другой вариант приемлем; Кто знает, может быть, показатели были и более высокие - в этих случаях вводные слова играют роль структурного элемента предложения.

Comment: В приведенном вами примере "Детали - это не главное (их можно опустить), главное - это чтобы было интересно.", - главное - действительно подлежащее. Но я бы не стал приравнивать ваш пример к примеру Розенталя : "Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно". Главное предложение не позволяет отнести слово "главное" к члену предложения, поскольку есть противительный союз а при вводным слове и отсутствует отрицание в главном предложении.Как, например, в вашем примере. В обсуждаемым же  примере, слово главное с союзом а указывает лишь на связь мыслей.

Comment: Серж, попробуйте сделать грамматический анализ предложения: вид предложения, все члены предложения. Только тогда будет ясна роль сочетания "а главное".

Comment: А тут все и так ясно: придаточное цели: детали можно опустить, а главное - чтобы было занимательно. Вводное слово является  структурным элементом предложения, поэтому опустить нельзя. София, вы считаете, что у Розенталя ошибка? Пример-то я брал из книги.

Comment: А мне кажется, что это ССП со следующим содержанием: составляя текст, детали можно опустить, но материал должен быть изложен интересно и увлекательно. Из всего этого можно сделать вывод, что перед нами предложение со смутной семантикой и неясной грамматикой, близкой к разговорной. Соответственно, этот пример не стоит использовать в качестве образца. Я, кажется, видела в Сети его разборку, но у меня этот ресурс не открылся. Попробуйте поискать.

Answer (score 1):

Тире после вводного слова А ГЛАВНОЕ - это, скорее, авторский знак. Всё зависит от структуры конкретного предложения и от наличия паузы.

(1) НЕТ ТИРЕ

Я их узнавал даже издали по их походке, покрою платья, а главное, по выраженью их лица.

Как ни красивы вальс и мазурка, но это несравненно и лучше, и красивее, и идет прямо от души, а главное, оригинальнее.

Другие шефы тоже стали учащать ко мне со своими визитами, но дарить было почти нечего, а главное, не за что.

Это уже совсем обидно, а главное, несправедливо.

Она была молода и красива, а главное, хитра и лукава.

(2) ТИРЕ СТАВИТСЯ

Как занят службой, а главное ― как рассудителен!

Это просто и красиво, а главное ― это искренно и верно!

Понемногу поправлялся, а главное ― восстановил некоторое доверие к самому себе.

Я бы в приведенном примере не стала ставить тире:

"В настоящее время логика, психология, рисование, конституция, а главное, филосОфия как предметы обучения в школе и вузе практически не используются".
В этом случае акцентируется слово "философия", на вводное слово ударение не падает.

Comment: Слово главное является вводным в значениях «особенно важно«особенно существенно. Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное, чтобы было интересно; Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно — запятую после союза а поставить нельзя, и для усиления выделения после вводного сочетания поставлено тире; Как крупный учёный, а главное как историк искусства, он пользуется большим авторитетом — в начале обособленного оборота.

Comment: "Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно": здесь "главное" - подлежащее, а "чтобы было занимательно" - сказуемое. Вводного слова нет.
Потому-то обычно после "а главное" и ставится запятая, а тире считается авторским знаком, чтобы не было путаницы со структурами. Вообще же действует базовое правило: вводные слова, как и любые обособленные обороты, выделяются СИММЕТРИЧНЫМИ знаками.

Comment: Тат, здесь "главное" не член предложения, а, следовательно, не подлежащее. Здесь именно вводное слово. Здесь  "главное" нельзя заменить на "Самый важный, основной, центральный" Именно в этом значении он членом предложения. Здесь же по смыслу "Что особенно важно, существенно"  - поэтому вводное!

Comment: Мнение Грамота.ру: Если стоит тире, "главное" - подлежащее, если стоит запятая, "главное" - вводное слово. Главное - не нырять в кастрюлю головой. Ситуация с "а главное" абсолютно идентична. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%C3%EB%E0%E2%ED%EE%E5+-+%ED%E5+%ED%FB%F0%FF%F2%FC+%E2+%EA%E0%F1%F2%F0%FE%EB%FE+%E3%EE%EB%EE%E2%EE%E9

Comment: Серж, вы сделайте грамматический разбор предложения. Это ССП, его трудно представить иначе.

Comment: Серж, вы привели объяснение Розенталя. Оно допустимо, но в данном случае оно не единственное.

Comment: Совершенно верно. И в тоже время Грамота говорит другое.

Вопрос № 246584
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить знаки препинания, используя оборот "а главное". В чем отличие выделения оборота двум запятыми и запятой - тире? 

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Как правило, после вводного "а главное" ставится или запятая, или тире.

Comment: На грамоте.ру. 

Указывает на то, что говорящий намерен высказать важную, особенно существенную мысль. Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в Прил. 2.

! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения.
 Вот мы и дома,  промолвил Николай Петрович, снимая картуз и встряхивая волосами. Главное, надо теперь поужинать и отдохнуть. И. Тургенев, Отцы и дети.

Comment: София, вы имеете в виду пример Аленки или Розенталя?

Comment: "Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное,  чтобы было интересно (интересную)". Здесь придаточное предложение в роли одного слова. Также вводное слово можно изъять. "Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно". Здесь придаточное предложение в роли сказуемого, и изъять "а главное"  невозможно.